# Wordpress - limite definido

Tags: php, wordpress

Instalei o wordpress seguindo esses passos:

```
Steps to Install Wordpress in Ubuntu 16.04

Step 1: Update the System
#apt-get update

Step 2: Install LAMP Server
#apt-get install lamp-server^

Step 3: Wordpress Database Initialization
#mysql -u root -p

Commands
CREATE DATABASE wordpressdb;
CREATE USER wordpressuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'wordpresspassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpressdb.* TO wordpressuser@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit

Step 4: Installing Wordpress
#cd /tmp
#wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
#unzip -q latest.zip -d /var/www/html/
#chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress
#chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/wordpress
#mkdir -p /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
#chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
```

Agora fui instalar um tema e apareceu:

```
**O arquivo ultrapassa o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.**
```

Como aumento o tamanho definido?

Comment: Máquina local ou alguma hospedagem?

Comment: Marquina local @Everson

Answer (score 3):

Procure pelo arquivo php.ini e configure o `upload_max_filesize`. Possivelmente, ele estará em `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Caso não esteja, tente localizar pelo locate ou pelo find.

Dentro do php.ini, configure os itens abaixo para evitar problemas de limites:

```
memory_limit = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128M
```

Depois de conseguir alterar, reinicie o apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Teste novamente a instalação do tema.

> Caso não encontre o arquivo php.ini, crie um arquivo php com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Localize o item **Loaded Configuration File**, ele vai conter o caminho do php.ini que está utilizando.

Comment: não achei o caminho `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Onde devo criar o arquivo?

Comment: @JuniorVilasBoas, crie um arquivo qualquer php e coloque o código phpinfo, execute o arquivo e procure pelo item Loaded Configuration File, lá estará o caminho do php.ini.

Comment: muito obrigada, voce ajudou muito :D